# Splitting one column into two with kable / kableExtra in R

Tags: r, kable, kableextra

this is my first so please be patient with me.

I want to split one column of a tibble into two columns depending on the value of a third column.

My table looks like this so far

```
Wertetabelle  <- tibble(DAT$Tag, DAT$Lauf, DAT$Replikate, DAT$Wert)  %>% group_by(DAT$Lauf)

Wertetabelle %>%
  mutate_all(linebreak) %>%
  kable(booktabs = T, digits = 2, 
        caption = "Rohdaten der PCR Messungen",
        col.names = linebreak(c("Tag", " Lauf", "Replikat", "Wert"), align = "r")) %>%
  kable_styling(latex_options = c("striped", "hold_position"))
```

This, unfortunately, gives me a very long table. The column "Wert" has at least 80 values.
So depending on the "Replikat" column which has two values (1:2) I could split up "Wert" into two columns with 40 values each.

Unfortunately, the `group_by` doesn't work, it seems.
Do you have any idea?

- Tag has 20 values 1:20
- Lauf has 2 values 1:2
- Replikat has 2 values 1:2
- Wert is numeric

Best
Werek

as requested please find the results of `dput(.)`

```
structure(list(`DAT$Tag` = structure(c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 
7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 
20L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 
14L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 20L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 
8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 20L, 
1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 
15L, 16L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 20L), .Label = c("1", "2", "3", "4", 
"5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11", "12", "13", "14", "15", 
"16", "17", "18", "19", "20"), class = "factor"), `DAT$Lauf` = structure(c(1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("1", 
"2"), class = "factor"), `DAT$Replikate` = structure(c(1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("1", 
"2"), class = "factor"), `DAT$Wert` = c(242L, 243L, 247L, 249L, 
246L, 244L, 241L, 245L, 243L, 244L, 252L, 249L, 242L, 246L, 247L, 
240L, 241L, 244L, 241L, 247L, 246L, 242L, 239L, 241L, 242L, 245L, 
246L, 245L, 239L, 246L, 251L, 248L, 240L, 249L, 248L, 238L, 244L, 
244L, 239L, 240L, 245L, 238L, 241L, 250L, 243L, 251L, 245L, 243L, 
244L, 247L, 247L, 251L, 251L, 248L, 245L, 239L, 245L, 237L, 247L, 
245L, 246L, 238L, 240L, 245L, 240L, 247L, 247L, 245L, 245L, 239L, 
241L, 246L, 245L, 240L, 246L, 242L, 248L, 242L, 245L, 242L)), row.names = c(NA, 
-80L), groups = structure(list(`DAT$Lauf` = structure(1:2, .Label = c("1", 
"2"), class = "factor"), .rows = structure(list(c(1L, 2L, 3L, 
4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 
18L, 19L, 20L, 41L, 42L, 43L, 44L, 45L, 46L, 47L, 48L, 49L, 50L, 
51L, 52L, 53L, 54L, 55L, 56L, 57L, 58L, 59L, 60L), c(21L, 22L, 
23L, 24L, 25L, 26L, 27L, 28L, 29L, 30L, 31L, 32L, 33L, 34L, 35L, 
36L, 37L, 38L, 39L, 40L, 61L, 62L, 63L, 64L, 65L, 66L, 67L, 68L, 
69L, 70L, 71L, 72L, 73L, 74L, 75L, 76L, 77L, 78L, 79L, 80L)), ptype = integer(0), class = c("vctrs_list_of", 
"vctrs_vctr", "list"))), row.names = 1:2, class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"), .drop = TRUE), class = c("grouped_df", 
"tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Comment: Re: The row "Wert" has at least 80 values.  Do you the column "Wert"?

Comment: Please provide a sample of your data. The output of `dput(.)` is typically unambiguous and preferred at times, though simpler methods might suffice depending on the contents of your frame. It would also be good if the sample demonstrates some variability (has complete 2-3 row sets to be broken down).

Comment: ARGHH I am an idiot. you mixed row and column.

The output from `dput(.) is too long to pe pasted in here.

Comment: Hi there, I added the dput(.) in the original post. Does anybody has any idea?